# What is dataProvider() in PyQGIS and what does it do?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm a beginner in PyQGIS and I've come across the dataProvider() function a few times now. The problem is I don't know what it does and what it's for. I have been searching everywhere for its meaning and use/s. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data provider is the connection to the underlying file or database
that holds the geospatial information to be displayed.

In QGIS, a data provider (instance of qgis.core.QgsVectorDataProvider) allows the vector/raster layer to access the features within the data source.
It includes a geometry type (stored in the data source), a list of fields that provide information about the attributes stored for each feature, and the ability to explore features within the data source (using getFeatures() method and QgsFeatureRequest class).

You can access the various data providers using the core.QgsProviderRegistry class.